# Quotes inside product description

Tags: importexport

My product data has quotes (as in "This is the best album yet!") in the product description field. This data is not current smart quotes.

Does this have to be converted to smart quotes in order not to choke the import process?

Answer (score 0):

No, you should leave those quotes as regular quotes. If you are generating these files yourself, then just follow the CSV format to escape a quote with another quote. If you are using Google Docs or Open Office, this will be done for you, so you do not have anything to worry about.

Do not use Excel as it tends to mangle files and introduce other errors.

For Magento 2 the documentation is here: http://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/system/data-csv.html

Comment: Thank you. The data file is being created programmatically, not inside OO/Google Docs/Excel. (10's of thousands of products).